# Why is Elementor not showing my custom widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building an Elementor extension plugin with widgets I am building. I am sectioning the plugin into namespaces and instantiating them with composer's autoloader. I am not receiving any errors but my widget is not showing up in the Elementor widget panel in the editor.

Widgets_Loader.php:

```
namespace WCSEA\Extras;

 use Elementor\Plugin;

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
     exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
 }
 
 final class Widgets_Loader {

     /**
      * Instance
      *
      * @since 1.0.0
      * @access private
      * @static
      * @var \WCS_Elementor_Addons\Plugin The single instance of the class.
      */
     private static $_instance = null;
 
     /**
      * Instance
      *
      * Ensures only one instance of the class is loaded or can be loaded.
      *
      * @since 1.0.0
      * @access public
      * @static
      * @return \WCS_Elementor_Addons\Plugin An instance of the class.
      */
     public static function instance() {
 
         if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
             self::$_instance = new self();
         }
         return self::$_instance;
     }

     /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Perform some compatibility checks to make sure basic requirements are meet.
     * If all compatibility checks pass, initialize the functionality.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {

        if ( $this->is_compatible() ) {
            add_action( 'elementor/init', [ $this, 'init' ] );
        }

    }

    // Run is_compatible()


    public function init() {

        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/register', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );
    }

    public function register_widgets( $widgets_manager ) {

        $widgets_manager->register( new \WCSEA\Elements\Navbar() );

    }
 
 }
```

In the main plugin file in the run function, I am invoking the static instance method:

```
function run_WCSEA() {
    \WCSEA\Extras\Widgets_Loader::instance();
    
    $plugin = new WCSEA\Core();
    $plugin->run();

}
```

Here is the namespace of the Navbar.php file

```
namespace WCSEA\Elements;

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

class Navbar extends Widget_Base {

}
```